# Есть две строки "abc" и "gfr". Нужно соединить их в одну, чтобы получилось "agbfcr" (буквы чередуются)

Tags: java, строки

Не могу понять в каком направлении двигаться. Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Что делал:
Преобразовал строки в два массива. char[]a = "abc" и char[]b = "gfr";
Создал третий char[] c = new char[a.length + b.Length];
И тут завис. Не могу понять как поочередно брать с каждого массива в определенном порядке элемент и добавлять его в третий массив.
Может не в том направлении пошел?

Comment: почитайте про конкатенацию строк. http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/rabota-so-strokami-v-java-osnovnye-metody-klassa-string/#concat или вам именно через `char[]` надо реализовать?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Не обязательно. Нужно решить, но я не так давно изучаю Java.

Comment: Про конкатенацию читал - подходящее что там нашел для этого задания - это действовать через char. Может я что-то еще упустил?

Comment: @Pavel: это не простое слияние (`a+b`) -- символы в результате перемежающиеся (на Питоне: [`''.join(map(''.join, zip(a, b)))`](https://ideone.com/el4dha) или [`''.join(map(add, a, b))`](https://repl.it/@zed1/interleaved-strings))

Comment: @jfs да, действительно, это я невнимательно прочитал вопрос.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая идея которая приходит на ум, заводить счётчик для каждого массива.
И заполнять по нему целевой массив.

```
public static char[] compound(char[] a, char[] b) {
     char[] c = new char[a.length + b.length];
     int ia = 0, ib = 0;
     while (1+ia+ib < c.length) {
         if (ia < a.length) {
             c[ia+ib] = a[ia];
             ia++;
         }
         if (ib < b.length) {
             c[ia+ib] = b[ib];
             ib++;
         }
     }
     return c;
}
```

В условии цикла  +1 потому что к примеру 0 + 0 < 1, хотя по идее это 2 элемента, т.к. длинна массива = 1 элементу

Comment: Попробовал проверить Ваше решение. Почему-то не может вызвать метод length в строке while(1 + ia + ib < c.length())?

Comment: @Жека скобки уберите, ошибся. Но не в этом суть, суть в самом алгоритме

Comment: Извиняюсь - мне нужно было быть самому внимательней! Спасибо, все работает!

Answer (score 3):

```
public static char[] method(char[] a, char[] b){
        //если a и b одинаковой длины
        char[] c = new char[a.length + b.length];
        for (int i = 0, j =0; i < a.length; j += 2, i++) {
            c[j] = a[i];
            c[j+1] = b[i];
        }
        return c;
}
```

счетчик j идет по новому, вдвое большему массиву, а i идет по маленьким массивам

Comment: можно даже без j - на каждом шаге она =2*i

Comment: Спасибо! Все прекрасно работает! Спасибо за помощь всем!!!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы объединить строки равной длины, чередуя символы с использованием Stream API:

```
/** ''.join(map(add, a, b)) */
static String interleaved(String a, String b)
{
    assert a.length() == b.length();
    return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.length(), b.length()))
            .mapToObj(i -> a.substring(i, i+1) + b.substring(i, i+1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Более эффективный вариант основан на наблюдении, что значения на чётных индексах равны первой строке, на нечётных — второй (вариация [@Valentine Anzhurov ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797774/23044)):

```
static char[] interleaved(char[] a, char[] b)
{
    assert a.length == b.length;
    char[] result = new char[a.length + b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        result[2*i] = a[i];     // result[::2] = a
        result[2*i+1] = b[i];   // result[1::2] = b
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/bnR1ll).

Все ответы (опубликованные на данный момент) разбивают суррогатные пары. В зависимости от задачи, можно попробовать чередовать code points или даже grapheme clusters.

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "abc";
string b = "def"

StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  res.append(a[i]);
  res.append(b[i]);
}

return res.toString()
```

Comment: [ошибка компиляции](https://ideone.com/jUz0lD)

Comment: @jsf На java никогда не писал, мой ответ скорее про алгоритм. Ошибку должно быть несложно исправить.